# Что за ошибка при установке yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, composer

При установке yii2 basic через composer стало выдавать ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте открыть в браузере `https://packagist.org/packages.json` Если не открывается, проблемы с сетью.

Comment: На компе не открывается этот сайт вообще, а на телефоне доступен...

Comment: Он доступен. Не используется прокси, случайно? DNS попробуйте прописать 8.8.8.8 (google)

Comment: Прописал днс, но изменений нет, сайт https://packagist.org также для меня недоступен

Comment: Ок, спасибо, теперь заработало, действительно видимо дело было в dns

Answer (score 0):

Несколько вариантов:
1. Нужно явно указать репозитории в composer.json (Add to composer.json) :

```
{
....
,
"repositories":[
    {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/vova07/yii2-users-module",
    "url": "https://github.com/vova07/yii2-rbac-module"
    }
]
}
```

2.Обновите композер:

```
composerself-update
```